# Weekly average of rows in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been asked to Create a by week average of temps ... and by zip code. The table has 15 million rows and would like shrink it by only 52 weeks per zip codes of 41K. Here is the Top 10 rows:

```
    postal_code Local_date  tempAvg_F   tempMax_F   tempMin_F
     1001       2015-07-14    74          83           65
     1001       2015-07-15    74          84           63
     1001       2015-07-16    67          78           57
     1001       2015-07-17    70          82           54
     1001       2015-07-18    73          82           67
     1001       2015-07-19    80          91           71
     1001       2015-07-20    81          92           71
     1001       2015-07-21    76          90           67
     1001       2015-07-22    73          83           59
     1001       2015-07-23    71          83           56
```

I have look over cte, AVG and group by, but wondering if using FOR EACH LOOP would be better. If someone could point me the right direction.

JJ

Answer (score 2):

> but wondering if using FOR EACH LOOP would be better

Loop/cursor in SQL world are in 95% cases slower than set based solution.

You can use simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT postal_code
      ,[week]               = DATEPART(wk, Local_date)
      ,[week_tempAvg_F]     = AVG(tempAvg_F)
      ,[week_tempMax_F]     = AVG(tempMax_F)
      ,[week_tempMin_F]     = AVG(tempMin_F)
FROM #tab
GROUP BY postal_code,DATEPART(wk, Local_date)
ORDER BY postal_code, [week];
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/381147)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════════╦══════╦════════════════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ postal_code ║ week ║ week_tempAvg_F ║ week_tempMax_F ║ week_tempMin_F ║
╠═════════════╬══════╬════════════════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
║        1001 ║   29 ║             71 ║             81 ║             61 ║
║        1001 ║   30 ║             76 ║             87 ║             64 ║
╚═════════════╩══════╩════════════════╩════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you. Now lets see how long is runs.